# Bitcoin RPC using PHP cannot createrawtransaction

Tags: php, bitcoin, bitcoind

```
$bitcoin->createrawtransaction("[{'txid' : \"5ffd30a03de02cbbea33f1e3a83d44f6ea90fd5c7be4ab28aae0698fbe451cc3\",'vout': 0}]","{\"2NFqqucqutcfQfmHpHhW3cNuPqRMX2LCLxC\": 0.6}"));
```

is completey failing its getting sent to bitcoind but that seems about it, I cant find where bitcoind error messages get returned so just get a 500 error. anyone give me some pointers?

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

Err messages get returned in-line if you're running the bitcoind (daemon). It's in the daemon folder if you're on windows (of the bitcoin-qt). I assume you know how to run it based on your question. So if you didn't see anything, there was no error. That said, I checked the blockchain and nothing was received. What are you trying to accomplish?